# Video chat for One to one Using java code for Android

Tags: android

Hi I am new to developing video chat application. Please help me how can i chat?

or

Any one please let me know that how to integrate skype to my application using android.

Thanks for in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi I am new to developing video chat application. Please help me how
>   can i chat?

I dont know if this will answer your question but in my experience in [Session Initiation Protocol](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) you can do Audio Calling , but the generic doesnt allow 3G and some phones ive tested doesnt work, that is why i moved to [imsdroid](https://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/) which is using doubango framework and is working for both Video/Audio calling and they even have samples for a working simple test app .

If you still want to pursue this kind of app I suggest reading this tutorial will give you more insight on the [client-side](http://kehers.github.io/2014/06/04/sip-on-android.html).

And this(If you want to setup your server) server [freeswitch](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_xml_curl) which will cater your client side for such protocol or if you want to test the client-side implementation you can as well use free sip servers as of now.

If you have manage to setup freeswitch and would like to register users dynamically i suggest reading this another tutorial to work dynamic registration for users http://saevolgo.blogspot.kr/2012/07/freeswitch-with-sip-users-in-mysql-mod.html

**NOTE: freeswitch is really a tough one to setup, i was using all the resources i have just to setup dynamic registration with new users using mod_xml_curl which freeswitch has(im using Amazon ec2 instance, in which freeswitch has tutorial for amazon ec2).**

*I hope this will benefit you as this benefits me :)*